# Accesing from web to my datasnap server

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, datasnap

I have created a DataSnap server with XE5 with 3 methods that will be access from a web site developed by another guy.

```
function Check_User( data : Double ) : TJSONObject;
function Check_Info( data : Double ) : TJSONObject;
function Insert_User( data : TJSONObject ) : string;
```

The 2 first functions works perfect. I receive a double variable as parameter, check my local db and returns the info required.
The web guy its calling this methods with

http://SERVER-IP:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods/Check_User/56638855 and

http://SERVER-IP:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods/Check_Info/56638855.

For the third function I need to receive a json string that I parse, insert into my local db and returns some id number in string format.

How he can access and send the parameter for my last function ?
If he try to use the same way as first functions, he gets

{"error":"TServerMethods.updateinsert_user method not found in the server method list"}

Thanks a lot for any help.

Regards

Leo

Comment: If you generate a JavaScript client for your server the JavaScript source should show the correct URLs and HTTP methods (GET, PUT...) for all server methods. This could be a starting point for the other guy.

Comment: Hi thanks for anwser. He told me that he can access my ds server with get for my first two functions but as he must send a long json string as a parameter for third function , he told me that it does not work the same way as the other functions. Do I need to make another method with something like http components for he to access , or how he can pass a json string as a parameter to consult my method ?